# Maven Eclipse plugin, WAR overlays, and dependencies on project vs. Maven repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a Maven web project that depends on other projects that build WAR targets, and then uses the other web projects as overlays.  All of these projects are part of a single parent project, imported into Eclipse as a Maven project.

The main web project's POM has dependencies and overlays with maven-war-plugin defined for the other modules.

*My problem*

in Eclipse, for some reason, when I update the Eclipse project from the Maven project, some of the modules are recognized as coming from other Eclipse projects, and others are expected to come from my Maven repository.

On closer inspection `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` shows a difference in the `dependent-module` for some modules.

```
<dependent-module ... handle="module:/overlay/prj/module1" />
```

vs.

```
<dependent-module ... handle="module:/overlay/var/M2_REPO/group/id/module2" />
```

Why would some modules be recognized differently than others?

Both are equally included as dependencies and overlays in the POM.

My workaround has been to edit this file by hand to get Eclipse to recognize that it should use the other Eclipse project directly (`module:/overlay/prj`) rather than look to the Maven repo.